# Listen for Foundation event in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, zurb-foundation, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm building an app in Vue.js with the general structure of:

```
<app>
    <filters-component></filters-component>
    <div class="off-canvas-content">
        <nav-component></nav-component>
        <div class="row card-grid">
            <card-component v-for="item in items">
                <modal-component v-if="launchModal === true"></modal-component>
            </card-component>
        </div>
    </div>
</app>
```

This allow me to render the modal on the DOM only if a data element of `launchModal` is set to true (after clicking the button to launch the modal). This works great, but I need to do the reverse when it's closed.

According to Foundation's documentation, the Reveal (modal) component should emit an event called `closed.zf.reveal` when it's closed.

How do I listen for this event on the parent element (card-component) and then change `launchModal` to false, when it's called?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the Vue code for `modal-component`?

Comment: Here's a gist of the two components. I'm sure I'm doing a lot wrong on this, this is my first time using Vue on a large app, be gentle. LOL! I know a lot of the JS could be refactored, I'm just trying to get everything working first ;)

https://gist.github.com/DinsmoreDesign/64d2e45119e842838507c192283ff8c8

FYI: The data that's being passed is coming from an API call on the parent App and is passed through props.

Comment: That's the card, component, can we see the modal component?

Comment: It's on there, you'll need to scroll down a bit ;)

Comment: Derp. I see it. I think it will be `this.$el` then in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially this will likely boil down to, in your `modal-component` (add these to the script in Modal.vue)

```
methods:{
    onModalClosed(){
        this.$emit("modal-closed")
    }
},
mounted(){
    this.$el.addEventListener('closed.zf.reveal', this.onModalClosed)
},
beforeDestroy(){
    this.$el.removeEventListener('closed.zf.reve‌​al', this.onModalClosed)
}
```

Or something to that effect, depending on what element emits the event. If some other element emits the `closed.zf.reveal` event, then you could add a `ref="modal"` to it and then use `this.$refs.modal.addEventListener` and `this.$refs.modal.removeEventListener`.

Then you could just

```
<modal-component v-if="launchModal === true"
                 @modal-closed="launchModal = false">
</modal-component>
```

### Edit

So the issue with listening to the event is that Foundation is using jQuery to fire the event. That means that you cannot listen for it using native methods (`addEventListener`), you have to listen to it with jQuery. So the modified code from above would be this:

```
methods:{
    onModalClosed(){
        this.$emit("modal-closed")
    }
},
mounted(){
    $(this.$el).on('closed.zf.reveal', this.onModalClosed)
},
beforeDestroy(){
    $(this.$el).off('closed.zf.reve‌​al', this.onModalClosed)
}
```

And this does, in fact, catch the event. The problem is that Foundation, for whatever reason, moves the modal *outside* of the Vue and appends it to the bottom of the document when the modal is initialized. That causes Vue to throw an error when `launchModal` is set to `false` because the modal is no longer *inside* the Vue, and Vue complains when it tries to remove it from the DOM.

That being the case, I suggest you use your `v-if` *inside* the modal for the [things that are rendering very slowly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43668988/can-i-dynamically-create-destroy-vue-components). That will result in a component like this.

```
Vue.component("modal", {
  props:["show"],
  template: "#modal-template",
  watch:{
    show(newVal){
      if (newVal)
        $(this.$el).foundation("open")
    }
  },
  methods:{
    onModalClosed(){
      this.$emit("modal-closed")
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    new Foundation.Reveal($(this.$el))
    $(this.$el).on("closed.zf.reveal", this.onModalClosed);
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    $(this.$el).off("closed.zf.reveal", this.onModalClosed);
  }
});
```

And the template is

```
<template id="modal-template">
  <div class="reveal" data-reveal>
    <div v-if="show">
      Stuff that is expensive to render
    </div>
    <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</template>
```

And here is the working [example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/YVZOZV?editors=1010).

Comment: don't forget `beforeDestroy(){this.$el.removeEventListener('closed.zf.reveal', () => this.$emit('modal-closed'))}`

Comment: @BertEvans Thanks! This makes perfect sense to me, but for some reason still isn't working. I assume the event on the modal-component should actually be `@modal-closed`, as referenced on the component's mounted/beforeDestroy life cycles, but this still isn't switching it to false for some reason. I'm wondering if the modal actually isn't emitting that event, after all? Honestly, Foundation 6's JS documentation is terrible.

Comment: @MatrixClaw yes, the event name is wrong on the listener. I fixed that. I'll take a look at the docs.

Comment: That would be awesome! Thank you!

Comment: @MatrixClaw I have an understanding now. Join the room I invited you to.

Comment: Your `removeEventListener` won't work, because the function isn't the same (they're two closures that do the same thing). Probably use a method.

Comment: @RoyJ Thanks :) Updated.

Comment: You know what's even worse? `this` won't be right in the method. :( Or will it? Does Vue bind methods?

Comment: @RoyJ in which case? Final component example it's correct. Check the example.

Comment: @RoyJ Appears to bind. https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/a12d32a56df2519c9cdf8d2da9d9425876263f89/src/core/instance/state.js#L218